# How to use 2 correlated subqueries with Join and Conditional Aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 queries below for which I want the output to combine.

```
select distinct [User].UserID, fname,  lname, JobTitle
from [User] 
join [Order] on [User].UserID = [Order].UserID
```

| UserID | fname | lname | JobTitle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Smith | Engineer |
| 2 | Terry | Doe | Engineer |

```
select [order].UserID,
    (
        select avg(case when ReturnTypeID = 5 then 1.0 else 0 end) as DefectedRate
        from RentalItems 
        where RentalItems.OrderID = [Order].OrderID 
    ) as DefectedReturnRate
from [Order] 
where OrderID in (select OrderID from RentalItems where ReturnTypeID=5)
```

| UserID | DefectReturnRate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.66 |
| 2 | 0.33 |

**Desired Output**

| UserID | fname | lname | JobTitle | DefectReturnRate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Smith | Engineer | 0.66 |
| 2 | Terry | Doe | Engineer | 0.33 |

**The three tables I have are below:**

**User:** userID, fname, lname, JobTitle

**Order:** OrderID, UserID

**RentalItems**: RentalItemsID, OrderID

Comment: I don't know how to join 2 queries like that. I only know how to join tables. I am joining Order Because I need user info for the users that exist in Order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you just appear to need the user information, how about just joining it on?

```
select U.UserID, U.fname, U.lname, U.JobTitle,
    (
        select avg(case when ReturnTypeID = 5 then 1.0 else 0 end) as DefectedRate
        from RentalItems R
        where R.OrderID = o.OrderID 
    ) as DefectedReturnRate
from [Order] O
inner join [User] U on U.UserID = O.UserID
where O.OrderID in (select OrderID from RentalItems where ReturnTypeID = 5);
```

Note the use of nice short table aliases for clarity.

As an aside, should you find yourself needing to join 2 queries together you do it exactly the same as a table join e.g.

```
select *
from (
  {sub-query 1)
)
inner join (
  {sub-query 2)
) on {some condition}
```

Further to get a list of users who have an order, an `exists` clause is clearer than a join e.g.

```
select UserID, fname, lname, JobTitle
from [User] U 
where exists (select 1 from [Order] O where U.UserID = O.UserID)
```

Comment: Thanks for additional information. This is good learning material  as I am just starting :)